# Restrict some action access with count?

Tags: php

This is more like a security question. 
What is best practice to implement something like "counting specific page visits per x time by IP" and blocking that IP address if limit is exceeded?

Some steps:

1. user enters website
2. user selects product to buy
3. fills out forms and submits form
4. redirected to payment gateway

How can i restrict 5 form submitions per 30 seconds? If user makes 6 per 30 IP gets blocked for 30 minutes?

Thanks.

Comment: 2 opinions i could share, you can use active sessions that time out after half an hour or you could use a database variation maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want to store actions or requests in a database along with the [time()](http://php.net/time) they were made. Then it's a matter of running a simple [mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) to check if the user has exceeded their limit. Eg.

```
"SELECT * FROM `requests` WHERE 
    `request_time` > '".(time() - (30 * 60))."' AND
    `ip_address` = '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."';"
```

The [mysql_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) on this query should return less than 5.

You can run this query every time a user loads a page or submits your form and simply end the execution of the script.

You might also want to run a query occasionally to delete old rows, maybe using a cron job.